# My rails 4 page specific styles only get applied on page refresh in development mode using Chrome browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

Rails 4.0.2
ruby 2.1.0p0 (2013-12-25 revision 44422) [x86_64-darwin12.0]

If I navigate to the page admin/malone_tunes/show.html.erb through the browser the page is delivered with out the styles specified in assets/styles/admin/malone_tunes.css.scss being applied. If I then hit command-r(browser refresh) the page reloads with the correct styles applied. I thought that config.cache_classes = false and config.action_controller.perform_caching = false in config/development.rb would cause each page load to serve up a new version of the layout with the <%= yield(:head) %>. I can get things to work with *= require_tree ., but this applies all stylesheets to the view and for my own understanding of the asset pipeline I want to implement page specific styles. 
Thanks for any suggestions or documentation references:)

--config/environments/development.rb

```
  Skunkwerx::Application.configure do
    # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

    # In the development environment your application's code is reloaded on
    # every request. This slows down response time but is perfect for development
    # since you don't have to restart the web server when you make code changes.
    config.cache_classes = false

    # Do not eager load code on boot.
    config.eager_load = false

    # Show full error reports and disable caching.
    config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
    config.active_support.deprecation = :log

    # Raise an error on page load if there are pending migrations
    config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

    # Debug mode disables concatenation and preprocessing of assets.
    # This option may cause significant delays in view rendering with a large
    # number of complex assets.
    config.assets.debug = true
  end
```

--config/aplication.rb

```
config.assets.precompile += ['admin/application.css' 'admin/malone_tunes/show.css']
```

--views/layouts/admin/application.erb

```
<head>
  <title>Skunkwerx Admin Page</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "admin/application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => false %>
  <%= yield(:head) %>
  <%#= stylesheet_link_tag "admin/malone_tunes/show", media: "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "admin/application", "data-turbolinks-track" => false %>
  <!-- loads controller specific scripts only on refresh -->
  <%#= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

--views/malone_tunes/show.html.erb
    <% stylesheet 'admin/malone_tunes/show.css' %>

--helpers/application_helper.rb

```
  module ApplicationHelper

    def stylesheet(*files)
      content_for(:head) { stylesheet_link_tag(*files) }
    end
  end
```

--assets/stylesheets/admin/application.css.scss

```
  *= require_self
  *= require admin/main
```

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that the javascript_include_tag is causing this when I comment it out the styles work as expected. I feel like this must be a bug in the asset pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem with my css and js files.
There is nothing wrong with the asset pipeline.

I corrected this problem by using the javascript_include_tag once and only once in my layouts/application.html.erb file.
Same with the stylesheet_link_tag. Only use it once.

Instead of making two statements, do this,

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "admin/application", params[:controller], "data-turbolinks-track" => false %>
```

and this...

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "admin/application", "admin/malone_tunes/show", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => false %>
```

Thank You for posting your issue, it pushed me to figure out this solution.

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the Rails asset pipeline using a feature called Turbolinks for sending CSS and JS assets to the browser. Turbolinks uses AJAX to load assets without refreshing the page. Problems can occur with popular javascript and css libraries such as jQuery/Chosen. A developer/user may notice the only way to make the assets work is with a manual browser refresh.

Josh Frankel describes this issue and provides a solution:

http://joshfrankel.me/blog/2015/fix/rails-4-turbolinks-fix-for-jquery-only-working-after-hard-refresh/

Basically:

1. add `gem 'jquery-turbolinks'` to Gemfile
2. bundle to reload your gems.
3. in `app/assets/javascripts/application.js` place `//= require jquery.turbolinks` after `//= require jquery` and before `//= require turbolinks`.
4. Restart any running instances of the Rails server and re-compile assets.